# SQL - return items in database that have minimum lecture_hours

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Trying to retrieve the module_names that have the minimum lecture_hours.

My table is **cs_course_modules** and looks like this:

```
module_name      |   module_id   |  etc  | lecture_hours| semester_taught |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Computing               CS11002     5       22          first semester 
Mathematics             CS11003     5       33          first semester
Advanced Math           CS22001     5       22          first semester
Data Structures         CS22002     5       33          first semester 
Computer Architecture   CS22003     5       33          first semester
```

It should return:

*Advanced Math and 
Computing*

My query I'm trying is:

```
SELECT module_name
FROM cs_course_modules
WHERE
    lecture_hours=(
        SELECT 
            MIN(lecture_hours)
        FROM
            cs_course_modules);
```

I'm getting the error: "table cs_modules doesn't exist".

Any guidance on what I need to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query [works for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v6aUJ4DYbmKYGkDyAA9N1c/0).

Comment: Are you working in the correct DB since you don't have one with your table?

Answer (score 0):

Check the schema where you have defined the table. 
Sometimes if synonyms are not defined you will have to qualify the table name with the schema name.
e.g. if the table employee is defined in schema emp then if you are running the query from a different schema ( assuming the other schema has access to employee table) you should use

select * 
from emp.employee;